# how to get the second equation (related to summation)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, self-learning

$$V(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N [\frac{N^2}{n^2}] (Y_i-Y_j)^2 \frac{n(N-n)}{N(N-1)} $$    for $i< j$

Equation(2.5) $$=(\frac{(N-n)}{n(N-1)})\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N (Y_i-Y_j)^2 $$ for $i< j$

we know that $$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} =\sum_{i=1}^N a_{ii} +2 \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij}$$  if $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$  for $i<j$

using this above identity in thi right hand side of (2.5), we get,

> > $$ V(Y) = \frac{(N-n)}{2n(N-1)} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N (Y_i -Y_j)^2 -\sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - Y_i)^2\right\}  $$
> >
> > $$ = \frac{(N-n)}{2n(N-1)} \left\{2 \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N Y_i^2 -2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N Y_iY_j\right\} $$

How can the second equation be obtained from the first equation in the gray box? While studying a proof, I'm stuck with that point of the proof. Please clearly explain how to obtain. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you copying this or evaluating this on your own? There are mistakes: 1) missing $N$ in numerator (if your first equation is correct), 2) the expression that follows "we know that..." is incorrect. Are you sure the equations in the highlighted grey box, which my answer is based upon, are correct?

Comment: I'm copying a book.this is the part of a proof, not whole proof.  since i dint write all parts of that proof, you saw this as if there were mistakes.@ki3i

Comment: No, I am not misinterpreting, there are mistakes in what you have written. For instance, when you write "We know that ..." you should have written $$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} =\sum_{i=1}^N a_{ii} +2 \sum_{i<j}^{N} a_{ij},$$ and not what you wrote. Furthermore, using this identity is completely unnecessary, since the last expression in the grey box follows directly from (2.5) by using the non-zero part of my answer below. Do you agree?

Comment: In fact, going directly from (2.5) shows that in your last expression you should not have a factor of "2" in the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concentrating on the terms in the brackets, one finds: 
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N (Y_i -Y_j)^2 -\sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - Y_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}(Y_i^2-2Y_iY_j+Y_j^2) + 0 \\= \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NY_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NY_iY_j + \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NY_j^2= 2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NY_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^NY_iY_j\,.
$$